# Where do recursive functions end?

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int n);
void main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter your number : " );
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n <= 1)
    {
        printf("The factorial of the number n is ",n);
    }
    else
    {
        int res = factorial(n);
        printf("The result is %d\n",res);
    }
}
int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

I'm doing a recursive function concept for the first time and i pretty much got like a 65% grasp on the concept of recursion. In the above program i have written a factorial recursion function and it goes normally well and i get the output but i'm trying to think where the recursion ends

Like for example i have gave an input of 5 :

```
The result is 120
```

but the main thing i wanted is why it doesn't continue after 0, if n <= 1(given if n = 0,-1...and so on during recursion) and then it should keep on returning "1" and multiplying with the recursion function(the factorial function being called inside the "factorial" function).In conclusion I really have no idea where the recursion ends...can you please clear it up.

Comment: 65% - how do you arrive at that number? Just curious, :)

Comment: "why it doesn't continue after 0" it doesn't continue after `n == 1`. Read the code, how does it handle that? Does it call a method, or does it do something else?

Comment: @SouravGhosh 73% of statistics is made up on the spot.

Comment: When `n <= 1`, you're returning just `1`, not `1 * factorial(n - 1)`. Since `factorial` isn't called here, `n = 0, -1, ...` will not happen

Comment: @VLAZ that has a 87% probability of being wrong, and 67% people does that 91% of time.

Comment: @AndyTurner So you're saying that if n ==1 then return 1 can cause the function to end?

Comment: @Aryan Of course -- if it doesn't recurse, the recursion ends.

Comment: @Spikatrix then the last returning value will be 1 but not 120 right?

Comment: @Aryan Yes, it will be `1`. Then the previous function call continues returning `n * the_value_returned` and so on. Finally, you get `120` as the output

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh the number arrived in me

Comment: @Spikatrix is it like, bear me with it but it's definitely like the innermost function will be called(like in terms of recursion) and it'll return the outermost function value right?..So it's basically the order 1*2*3*4*5  = 120 not 5*4*3*2*1 = 120

Comment: @Aryan The wording is a bit off, but yeah you get the idea. The innermost function does return first and that value bubbles up to outer function return calls and finally, the last value is returned to the main function.

Comment: But you're right on....Blessings of Akatosh are with you

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have call `factorial(3)`, then the call-chain will be something like this:

```
factorial(3)  // Initial call
    factorial(2);
        factorial(1);
            return 1;  // No more recursion
        return 2 * 1;  // 1 is the result of factorial(1)
    return 3 * 2;  // 2 is the result of factorial(2)
```

The result of `factorial(3)` will be `6` (`3 * (2 * 1)`).

Comment: Oh my god....it's like the innermost function(in terms of recursion) will be executed first and it will return the outermost function return value?

Answer (score 2):

> In conclusion I really have no idea where the recursion ends..

It ends at the `return 1;` statement:

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;  <---- Here
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

Maybe it's more clear if you wrote it like:

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
    {
        // No more recursive calls - just return 1
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do recursive call with decremented argument
        return n * factorial(n-1);
    }
}
```

So the code keeps doing recursive calls until `n` becomes 1. Then it returns 1 to the previous recursive call which returns 2 (2 * 1) to the previous recursive call which returns 6 (3 * 2) to the previous recursive call which returns 24 (4 * 6) .... and so on.

So the final result is calculated like:

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * ...
\---/   
  2   * 3
\-------/
    6     * 4
\-----------/
      24
```

Comment: You just made my mind blown...Common W..and PS this concept can be used in Java and Python right?

Comment: @Aryan I don't know much about java and python but I do assume that they support recursive calls

Comment: Blessings of Akatosh are with you

Answer (score 0):

From [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion):

> In mathematics and computer science, a class of objects or methods exhibits recursive behavior when it can be defined by two properties:

> - A simple base case (or cases) — a terminating scenario that does not use recursion to produce an answer.

> - A recursive step — a set of rules that reduces all successive cases toward the base case.

So, terminating scenario('s)/condition('s) is one of property of recursion and it's where the **recursion ends**.

In context of your program:

Your program is finding the factorial of a given number `n`.

The factorial of a non-negative integer `n` is the product of all positive integers less than or equal to `n`:

```
n ! = n * ( n − 1 ) * ( n − 2 ) * ( n − 3 ) * ..... * 3 * 2 * 1
```

which is equivalent to

```
n ! = n * ( n - 1 ) !
```

that means, when writing program to calculate the factorial of a number `n`, we have to calculate the product of all positive integers and stop when reached to `1`, which is the terminating condition.

In `factorial()` function:

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

The condition `if(n <= 1)` is the terminating condition for recursive function finding the factorial of `n` and its where the recursive function `factorial()` ends.

**Additional**:

- In your program, you are missing the format specifier in this
  `printf()` statement:

  `printf("The factorial of the number n is ",n);`

it should be

```
printf("The factorial of the number n is %d\n",n);
                                         ^^
```

- Note that, `0!` is `1` and, after making above change, your program
  will give output as `0` when user give input number `0` which is
  wrong.

May you should write function to calculate factorial of given positive number `n` like this:

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

and add a check on user input before calling `factorial()`. This will take care of `0!` as well.

- Using `void` as return type of `main` function is not as per
  standards. The return type of `main` function should be `int`.

Answer (score 0):

To understand simple recursive code, it helps a lot to draw a diagram (recursive trace). I will draw it in paint, but it's even better to do it on paper. 
Let's say we are calling `factorial(3)`.

1. **Write down the call of the function.** (In the beginning, it's `factorial(3)`)
2. **Ask yourself: "Is the exit condition satisfied?"** (In your case the condition is `if(n <= 1)`)

   - **If the answer is yes, check what gets returned and write it under the previous function call, then go to the next step.** 
      You have `return 1;` so `1` gets returned.
   - **If the answer is no, check what gets returned and write it under the previous function call.** You have `return n*factorial(n-1);` so the first time the return value will be `3*factorial(3-1)`, which is equal to `3*factorial(2)`. **Now go back to step 1) with the new function call and repeat the process until the condition is satisfied**. The call here is `factorial(2)`. 
      You can also connect the function calls with arrows to make the diagram more organized.

This is how the diagram should look like when your condition is satisfied:
[image: diagram after step 2]

3. You now go from the bottom upwards:
   **Write down the value of the very bottom function call, and repeat for every function call above that.**
    In your case, you first write the value of `factorial(1)`, which is `1`, then you move up, and you see that `factorial(2)` is equal to `2*factorial(1)`. And because you know that `factorial(1)` is equal to `1`, you also know that
   `factorial(2)` is equal to `2`.

    You can connect the function calls upwards to make the diagram more organized.

You are done. The diagram should look something like this:
[image: final diagram]

With this diagram, we know exactly when the recursion stops - when `factorial(1)` is called. We also know the end result, which is `6`.